# Python: Turn String in List of Lists to a float

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list within a list that goes like this:

```
data = [["Apple", "fruit", "1533" "1455"], ["BANANA", "fruit", "1853", "1568"], 
["Broccoli", "vegetable", "1652", "1453"]]
```

I am trying to turn the 3rd item into a float from a string, so I can find the max of the column. I keep having issues due to it being a list of a list, instead of it being just a single list. Any help would be great.

Comment: "I am trying to turn the 3rd item into a float from a string" The "'third item" *of what*?

Comment: `max(float(a[2]) for i in data)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang This, but typo (`a` is not `i`). I'd suggest more descriptive naming (`max(float(datum[2]) for datum in data)`), makes it easier to spot :)

Comment: Third item of each sublist? Please edit the question to make it slightly more clear and I can help out

Comment: Also, OP, the first sublist is actually equal to `["Apple", "fruit", "15331455"]`; you might have a typo in your code as well?